# What are "neural-kinetics"?

Tags: the-matrix

In *The Matrix* (1999), Mouse [watches Neo's moves on a computer screen](https://www.youtube.com/watch?t=231&v=fhrNgXJ__n8&feature=youtu.be)

> **Mouse:** *Jeezus Keeerist! He's fast! **Take a look at his neural-kinetics!** They're way above normal!*

**What are "Neural-kinetics"?**

Comment: I've taken the liberty of correcting the question. The official script book has the line "*Jeezus Keeerist! He's fast! Look at his neural-kinetics! They're way above normal!*"; https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFVCT.png

Comment: This line was added quite late in the day. The 1996 first draft has an unused character called Cable, Mouse and Tank chatting "**CABLE:** *Jeezus Keerist! That boy is fast!*    **MOUSE:** *You ever seen anyone that fast that soon, Tank?* **TANK:** *Never.*" and the 1997 second draft has the rest of the conversation removed entirely "**MOUSE:** *Jeeezus Keeerist!  That boy is fast!*"

Comment: For the record, there's nothing in *The Art of the Matrix* about this line or why it was amended so much. I've been through all of the Matrix comics and this appears to be the only mention of neural-kinetics. If I had to *guess*, I'd assume that it just means how fast you can move your body with your mind inside the world of The Matrix (**neural** = of or relating to the nervous system, **kinetic** = of or relating to movement of an object)

Comment: @Valorum My younger self always understood it somewhere in the line of: they are checking his brain(waves), and it's processing information really fast; although I will have to admit that I don't have any proof for what my younger self used to believe when The Matrix first came out.

Comment: @Clockwork - I'm not going to post an answer that says that. I'll wait for some other poor schmuck to do it, then demand proof, then downvote it when they can't provide any :-)

Comment: @Clockwork - It might be worth looking at some of the overseas subtitles to see if they contain any clues.

Comment: @Valorum Yeah, I tried doing that once again. The French version merely translated "neural-kinetics" into "neuro-cinétique" (basically just neural and kinetic). And in the actual dubbing, the guy said "neuro-kinèse" which I believe was to try to remain consistent with the English pronunciation, even if it sounds like he's talking about kinesis instead of kinetics.

Comment: For this one, my vote goes for mashed up technobabble.

Comment: I don't recall anything canonical here either. I also watched this scene with the "in-movie experience" and the cast/crew commentaries on and neither touch on this.